# Why \pgfkeyssetvalue uses a token list?

Tags: token-lists

The `\pgfkeyssetvalue` is defined by (in `pgfkeys.code.tex` file):

```
\long\def\pgfkeyssetvalue#1#2{%
  \pgfkeys@temptoks{#2}\expandafter\edef\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{\the\pgfkeys@temptoks}%
}
```

where `\pgfkeys@temptoks` is a token list.

Why the following code (where I use `\def` instead of `\edef`) is not equivalent?

```
\long\def\pgfkeyssetvalue#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

In other words, why `\pgfkeyssetvalue` uses a token list?

Comment: As the comments before says: So that the token list can also contain things like `#1`. `\pgfkeyssetvalue{blub}{abc#9#1}` works fine with the original definition but with your alternative definition you get an error: "Illegal parameter number in definition".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer With your example, it is now obvious. Can you turn your comment into answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using an intermediary toks register the user can store argument parameters (`#1, #2`) without having to manually double the `#` in the input. This means that things like `\pgfkeyssetvalue{blub}{abc#1}` will work. Without the toks-register trick an input like `\pgfkeyssetvalue{blub}{abc##9##1}` would be needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newtoks\mytoks
\mytoks{abc#1#2}
\edef\blub{\the\mytoks}

%\show\blub gives:
% > \blub=macro:
% ->abc##1##2.

%\def\blub{abc#9#1} %error

\end{document}
```